# Слайдер контента.

Tags: html, css, javascript

Добрый день!
Нужен слайдер:

слева есть пять блоков,а справа есть блок с картинкой,и нужно сделать так чтобы при :hover на div слева выводился соответствующий img.
Поделитесь ссылкой или покажите пример плз.

Comment: я не дружу с jQuery мб кто нить покажете пример плз,срочно надо .
Всем буду благодарен хоть в глубине души )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jquery ?
www.jquery.org

скрипт что то типа

```
$(document).ready(
  function(){
    $(".leftBlock").hover(function(){
      $("#image").attr("src",$(this).attr("image_src"))},
      function(){$("#image").attr("src","default_image_url");}
  });
```

левые дивы делаются классом leftBlock,  и в аттрибут дива image_src пишем урл картинки для показа в див с id="image"

```
<html>
<head>
<script type = "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
      function(){
        $(".leftBlock").hover(function(){
          $("#image").attr("src",$(this).attr("image_src"))},
          function(){$("#image").attr("src","default_image_url");}
      });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="leftBlock" image_src="image1.jpg">
Left Block 1
</div>
<div class="leftBlock" image_src="image2.jpg">
Left Block 2
</div>
<div class="leftBlock" image_src="image3.jpg">
Left Block 3
</div>
<div class="leftBlock" image_src="image4.jpg">
Left Block 4
</div>
<div class="leftBlock" image_src="image5.jpg">
Left Block 5
</div>

 <div id="image_div" ><img id="image" src="default.jpg"/></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: надо подключить 
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  ?

Comment: Все исправил ,у тебя там просто LeftBlock а у div id стоит LeftBody.
Спасибо помог!.

Comment: Да, спасибо, поправил

Comment: да jquery надо конечно подключить

Comment: Все сделал ,работает,еще раз спасибо!

Comment: Подскажи а как сделать чтобы hover оставался на на последнем элементе с которого отвел мышку.(Например навел на div4 убрал и остался hover на нем и так со всеми ) ?

Comment: Убери $("#image").attr("src","default_image_url");

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/hover/